# Overriding a method m(List<A> listOfA) with a version that needs to assume A's are of class B extending A without having to cast each element

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, extends

Just ran into a modeling problem I had not seen before.

Suppose I have a class for French people, another for Doctors, and another for FrenchDoctors, and I want to write the following:

```
///////// FRANCE

interface FrenchPerson {}

void frenchSpecificBureaucraticProcedure(List<? extends FrenchPerson> frenchPeople) {
    // ...
}

///////// DOCTORS

interface Doctor {}

class DoctorsAssociation {
    void includeNewMembers(List<? extends Doctor> doctors) {
        // ... do stuff
    }       
}

///////// FRENCH DOCTORS

interface FrenchDoctor extends FrenchPerson, Doctor {}

class FrenchDoctorsAssociation extends DoctorsAssociation {

    @Override
    void includeNewMembers(List<? extends Doctor> frenchDoctors) {
        // ERROR: frenchDoctors is List<? extends Doctors>
        // but frenchSpecificBureaucraticProcedure requires List<? extends FrenchDoctor>
        frenchSpecificBureaucraticProcedure(frenchDoctors);

        super.includeNewMembers(frenchDoctors);
    }
}
```

My first impulse was to override `includeNewMembers` using a `List<? extends FrenchDoctor>` parameter instead:

```
    @Override
    void includeNewMembers(List<? extends FrenchDoctor> frenchDoctors) {
        frenchSpecificBureaucraticProcedure(frenchDoctors);
        super.includeNewMembers(frenchDoctors);
    }
```

but that does not work because the Java compiler considers this a different method from `DoctorsAssociation::includeNewMembers`.

The only way I can get it to work is by doing an unchecked cast:

```
    @Override
    void includeNewMembers(List<? extends Doctor> frenchDoctors) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FrenchDoctor> frenchFrenchDoctors = (List<FrenchDoctor>) frenchDoctors;
        frenchSpecificBureaucraticProcedure(frenchFrenchDoctors);
        super.includeNewMembers(frenchDoctors);
    }
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this (that is, without unchecked casts).

Comment: I often think the simplest way to explain a concept or idea is in terms of Western European governmental processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make the `DoctorsAssociation` class generic:

```
public class DoctorsAssociation<T extends Doctor> {
   void includeNewMembers(List<T> doctors) {
        // ... do stuff
    }
}
```

and then declare your `FrenchDoctorsAssociation` class as

```
public class FrenchDoctorsAssociation extends DoctorsAssociation<FrenchDoctor> {

    @Override
    void includeNewMembers(List<FrenchDoctor> frenchDoctors) {
       // you now already have List<FrenchDoctor> to work with without casting
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good because one can think of `DoctorsAssociation` as a kind of container of `Doctor`. In my real situation (not shown as this was simplified), that is not the case. I have two classes and they refer to each other and are more parallel, so it's harder to think about one being a container of the other. I am not too unhappy about the unchecked cast once I realize `MyClass.equals(Object another)` has to do an unchecked cast, too. I think this is analogous to that, because it's about class extensions knowing about types only dynamically. If the language can do it, I guess I can too.